# how to make i18n content searchable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, search-engine, i18n-gem

i want to make my multilingual site searchable which is fully static . The site shares 3 languages .  I use a technique which captures unique tag content with its respective locale file ( it's in yml) like

#### In my view files

```
<%= t ".unique_key" %>
```

#### In my locale file

```
en:
  filename:
    unique_key: "This is unquie content which i want to search"
```

Currently , I tried googling but didn't found any solution. The only thing which my minds clicks is make a my local site site crawler . 
How did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This post by Google might help: [Working with multilingual websites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html).

The **Crawling and Indexing your multilingual site** section should answer your question.